# How do I implement a MailChimp API form embed?

Tags: php, html, css

sorry for the perhaps naive question, but I have absolutely 0 experience in web design and I've been plowing through .html/.css for 2 days straight, and I think it's time I just seek some help.

I'm making a simple landing page for a conference, and I've been using a few templates. The most recent template I'm using is perfect, except the email signup sends direct emails to my account, rather than creating a list using a service such as mailchimp - highly inefficient.

A previous template I tried out, however, did implement mailchimp, and I was wondering how I might just grab its code and throw it in the current template I have.

Here is the subscribe.php from the mailchimp template:

```
<?php
$apiKey = '';
$listId = '';
$double_optin=true;
$send_welcome=true;
$email_type = 'html';
$email = $_POST['email'];
//replace us2 with your actual datacenter
$submit_url = "http://us1.api.mailchimp.com/1.3/?method=listSubscribe";
$data = array(
    'email_address'=>$email,
    'apikey'=>$apiKey,
    'id' => $listId,
    'double_optin' => $double_optin,
    'send_welcome' => $send_welcome,
    'email_type' => $email_type
);
$payload = json_encode($data);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $submit_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, urlencode($payload));
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
$data = json_decode($result);
if ($data->error){
    echo $data->error;
} else {
    echo "Thanks! We'll keep you updated on the conference :)";
}
?>
```

and here is the snippet of code in index.html:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-md-offset-3 subscribe">
    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="subscribe.php" id="subscribeForm" method="POST">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-offset-0">
          <input class="form-control input-lg" name="email" type="email" id="address" placeholder="Enter your email" data-validate="validate(required, email)" required="required">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-4">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg">SIGN UP TO BE NOTIFIED</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
    <span id="result" class="alertMsg"></span> </div>
</div>
```

For reference, here are the subscribe.php and index.html snippets from the non-mailchimp template:

Subscribe.php

```
<?php
 if ( isset( $_POST['newsletter_submit'] ) ) {
// Initialize error array
 $newsletter_errors = array();
// Check email input field
 if ( trim( $_POST['newsletter_email'] ) === '' )
 $newsletter_errors[] = 'Email address is required';
 elseif ( !preg_match( "/^[_\.0-9a-zA-Z-]+@([0-9a-zA-Z][0-9a-zA-Z-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z] {2,4}$/i", trim( $_POST['newsletter_email'] ) ) )
  $newsletter_errors[] = 'Email address is not valid'; 
  else
  $newsletter_email = trim( $_POST['newsletter_email'] );
// Send email if no input errors
  if ( empty( $newsletter_errors ) ) {
  $email_to = "register@neustep.org"; // Change to your own email address
  $subject = "NeuSTEP Subscription";
  $body = "Subscriber details: " . $newsletter_email . "\r\n";
  mail( $email_to, $subject, $body, $headers );
  echo 'Thank you for subscribing!';
  } else {
  echo 'Please go back and correct the following errors:<br />';
  foreach ( $newsletter_errors as $error ) {
  echo $error . '<br />';
}}}
?>
```

Index.html snippet

```
<div class="newsletter">
 <form action="subscribe.php" method="post" id="newsletter-form">
  <p class="form-field">
   <label for="newsletter_email" class="visually-hidden">Your email address</label>
   <i class="icon ion-paper-airplane" aria-hidden="true"></i>
   <input type="text" name="newsletter_email" id="newsletter_email" value="" placeholder="Your email address" />
  </p>
  <p class="form-submit">
   <input type="submit" name="newsletter_submit" id="newsletter_submit" value="Get Notified" />
  </p>
 </form>
</div>
```

thanks for helping! sorry for the long post. I'm not sure what the etiquette on stackoverflow is, so if i'm asking a crappy question, let me know.

Comment: You just need to implement proper handler for subscribing. See my answer for detail [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23601984/how-do-i-implement-a-mailchimp-api-form-embed/23602244#23602244)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your form is ok, and you need to implement a handler for subscribing like;

**subscribe.php**

```
<?php
if (empty($_POST["newsletter_email"]) {
    die("You should provide email!");
} else if (!preg_match( "/^[_\.0-9a-zA-Z-]+@([0-9a-zA-Z][0-9a-zA-Z-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z] {2,4}$/i", trim( $_POST['newsletter_email'] ) )) {
    die("Email address is not valid!");
} else {
    $newsletter_email = trim( $_POST['newsletter_email'] );
}

$apiKey = '';
$listId = '';
$double_optin=true;
$send_welcome=true;
$email_type = 'html';
$email = $newsletter_email;
//replace us2 with your actual datacenter
$submit_url = "http://us1.api.mailchimp.com/1.3/?method=listSubscribe";
$data = array(
    'email_address'=>$email,
    'apikey'=>$apiKey,
    'id' => $listId,
    'double_optin' => $double_optin,
    'send_welcome' => $send_welcome,
    'email_type' => $email_type
);
$payload = json_encode($data);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $submit_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, urlencode($payload));
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
$data = json_decode($result);
if ($data->error){
    echo $data->error;
} else {
    echo "Thanks! We'll keep you updated on the conference :)";
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks! One other issue - the form in the mailchimp version doesn't format properly with the non-mailchimp template; is there a way to combine the mailchimp form with the formatting of the original one?

Comment: You want mailchimp form? I understand you wanted to use your own form

Comment: sorry for being unclear; i mean if I can use this with the MC API:


<div class="newsletter">
 <form action="subscribe.php" method="post" id="newsletter-form">
  <p class="form-field">
   <label for="newsletter_email" class="visually-hidden">Your email address</label>
   <i class="icon ion-paper-airplane" aria-hidden="true"></i>
   <input type="text" name="newsletter_email" id="newsletter_email" value="" placeholder="Your email address" />
  </p>
  <p class="form-submit">
   <input type="submit" name="newsletter_submit" id="newsletter_submit" value="Get Notified" />
  </p>
 </form>
</div>

Comment: wow okay sorry it's not formatted. it's the first index.html snippet

Comment: It is all ok then, right? Have you any other assistance? @user3627191

Comment: hey sorry, just one more question; i've editted my original post so it's easier to see my question. thank you so much again!

Comment: I am looking at your question, but you shouldn't be change your original question. Please post your question separately. Because incoming users cannot understand what is going on . Thanks

Comment: I have looked at your new question, what do you mean with correctly formatted? css?

Comment: yes, i meant proper css. i have asked a new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23603239/how-do-i-implement-a-mailchimp-api-in-a-email-signup-form

Comment: Could you please send me the url of mailchimp subscription form?

Comment: http://neustep.us8.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=69beb8ff020f5134822eb5b81&amp;id=bd384b6a84

Comment: but what i think the one im using uses the APIkey and listID

Comment: You can use mailchimp subscription widget in your page. See my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23603239/how-do-i-implement-a-mailchimp-api-in-a-email-signup-form)